# How to have state in Next.js if I want to statically generate site during build time?

Tags: next.js

Using Nextjs to create a basic ecommerce website.

I am using a fake API "fakestoreapi.com" to fetch products. Now I want to add `addedToCart` to each product (since it doesn't come with the API) and have it as a global state. As far as I know, and what I did in React was that I used the `Context API`.

In the `ProductsContext.js` file, what I'd do is `fetch` data in `useEffect` and pass it to `children` in `<ProductsContext.Provider>`. This is what I did in `React`.

But in Nextjs, while building the website, I used `useStaticProps` to in `Products` page to `fetch` all products. I also used it in `Details` page to fetch a single product that matched `dynamic route`. But then I can't have a global state.

And if I use a global state like Nextjs docs say, in `_app.js` file, It wont be statically generated? How do I do this? In React, I did all the `fetching` and then added `addedToCart` and shared it as global state all in client side.

Comment: Why don't you add `addedToCart` in `getStaticProps` before returning the data? If you're statically generating all pages you shouldn't need context to hold the data.

Comment: Other than Details page, I want that state to reflect in "Products" page too, each product card will have "add to cart" button when they hover, and the text will be either "add to cart" or "added to cart" or some icon based on state